# How to correctly update QTableView using timer?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qtableview

I use C++, Qt 4.8.5, Visual Studio 2010, SQLite. I have a Qt-based GUI application, which contains `QTableView`. The program analyzes some data and changes some cells without adding/removing rows. I use QTimer for refreshing `QTableView` using `OnManualSubmit` mode. Is it safe to call `submitAll()` method in the timer slot for the model several times even if there are no modifications? If `submitAll()` fails, then do I have to call `select()` method of my model manually? What about row fetching for SQLite - do I need it after `submitAll()` call in order to watch modifications of cells in the 257-th and further rows?

Sometimes I've got last error something like "Parameter count mismatch" (`QSqlError::StatementError`) after the second'submitAll()' call. What is the possible reason?  The program is multithreaded, working threads send data to the main thread. The timer triggers every 3 seconds (the changes are buffered). It is instead of instant cell update in `QTableView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not update your view directly (or by timer - it's a big overhead). You must call `emit dataChanged( ... );` on each data change in model. But if you want a dirty hack, you may simply call (from model) 'emit dataChanged( QModelIndex(), QModelIndex() );' when you need to update your view.

Comment: The program is multithreaded, working threads send data to main thread to be shown. Immediately showing each tiny cell update does not make GUI responsive, that's why I had to switch to manual submit mode.

Comment: Multithreading does not affect ui performance. It increace it. Just put necessary data to your cell (from any thread) and call `emit dataChanged()`. You should analyze your code for performance issues, if you have some.